# Getting name of an image by separating any other integers from pathname in python for face recognition

Tags: python-2.7

I want only names from pathnames.

Suppose my filename is albert.1.jpg. so i want only albert as output.

I tried this but it is printing whole list:

```
ID = str(os.path.split(imagePath)[1].split('.'))
print ID (output ['albert', '1', 'jpg'])
```

Please explain about slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not get "Why your code does not work?" but I tried the code which is given at below, on my pc to get "albert" from "albert.1.jpg" and it works (this python source file should be located in same path with your image files):

```
import os

current_path = os.getcwd()

for f in os.listdir(current_path):
    print(f.split(".")[0])
```

My folder contains the files;

albert.1.jpg

albert.2.jpg

getName.py

as like that:
[image]

and my python script prints out like that;
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot . that helped